# HOw to add playlist in jplayer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jplayer

Below is the code which plays an mp3 audio file.I can play only one file but i need multiple files to be played, i mean like an playlist.So,kindly help me out.Ita an jplayer.

thank you

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "media/test.mp3",

        }).jPlayer("play"); // auto play
    },
    ended: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "swf",
    supplied: "mp3"
})
.bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { // pause other instances of player when current one play
        $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can do the following.

I instantiate the player on page load:

```
jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
  swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
  supplied: "mp3",
  wmode: "window",
  preload:"auto",
  autoPlay: true,
  errorAlerts:false,
  warningAlerts:false
});
```

Then inside a listener, which will be unique for every item, you need to:     A) Fetch track name/URL, I guess you should be able to figure this out.

B) Pass the track to the setMedia

```
jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
  mp3: "http:xxxx.rackcdn.com/"+track+".MP3"
});
```

C) Play the track

```
jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
```

To get the track Id you need to install listeners on your playable items(maybe a a playable class?) and get the track from that one.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at [jPlayer Jukebox add-on](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jplayer-jukebox/). It is based on [jPlayer Playlist add-on](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) but adds extra functionality, such as ability to scan the page for media links and make them playable.

[image: jPlayer Jukebox add-on]